# Load HDF5 checkpoint models with custom metrics

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've created a Keras Regressor to run a RandomizedSearch CV using a ModelCheckpoint callback, but the training overran the Colab runtime 12H limit and stopped halfway through. The models are saved in `hdf5` format.

I used `tensorflow_addons` to add the `RSquare` class to monitor the R2 for train and validation sets. However, when I used `keras.models.load_model`, I get the following error:

[image]

As you can see from the traceback, I have passed the `custom_objects` parameter, but still it is not recognised.
How can I solve this?

You can see the full code example below:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, InputLayer
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

def build_model(n_hidden = 2, n_neurons = 64, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],), dropout = 0):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(InputLayer(input_shape = input_shape))
  for i in range(n_hidden):
    model.add(Dense(n_neurons, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = [tfa.metrics.RSquare(y_shape=(1,))])
  return model

keras_reg = KerasRegressor(build_model)
checkdir = os.path.join(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/COP328/Case A', 'checkpoints', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S'), 'imputed_log1p-{epoch:02d}-{val_r_square:.3f}.hdf5')

callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(checkdir, save_freq='epoch', save_best_only = True, monitor = 'val_r_square', mode = 'max'),
             EarlyStopping(patience = 10)]

# Here is where training got interrupted because of Colab runtime being dropped:

param_dist = {
    'n_hidden' : [1,2],
    'n_neurons': [8,16,32,64,128],
    'dropout': [0,0.2,0.4]
}

rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_dist, n_iter= 15, cv = 5)
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 200, batch_size = 64,
                  validation_data = (X_valid,y_valid),
                  callbacks = callbacks)

# Here is where I am trying to reload one of the most promising models based on R2, and getting the error: 

from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
rnd_model = load_model(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/COP328/Case A/checkpoints/26-06-2021_17-32-29/imputed_log1p-56-1.000.hdf5', custom_objects = {'r_square': tfa.metrics.RSquare, 'val_r_square': tfa.metrics.RSquare})
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't take into account the addons package but one possibility is to create the coefficient of determination (R^2) as a different metric without that package, and then defining it as your loss.

```
    def coeff_determination(y_true, y_pred):
        from keras import backend as K
        SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_true-y_pred ))
        SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_true - K.mean(y_true) ) )
        return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )
```

Recall that minimizing MSE will maximize R^2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I'll wait to see if someone can find the reason for the error in the traceback